# Post request Flask with dynamic URL and buttons in HTML

Tags: python, flask, request

I have a web app which serves football predictions to users. A postgres db stores the predictions and the website serves them according to the selected date. The first time the page loads, the db is queried according to today's date. If the user then presses one of the three buttons in the website (yesterday, today and tomorrow shown as 2020-1-11, 2020-1-12, 2020-1-13) the queries should change accordingly. I would like the url to change as well, e.g. /this_date/2020-1-12 so that I can then cache each of the queries. I have figured how to create the buttons and send the post requests but they all return to 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/this_date/'. Any ideas how to achieve the dynamic URL? I have spent countless hours searching for this and have seen other overflow posts (like using <>) but I cant seem to make it work. My code so far (only the relative parts, if you need more I can upload as well).

Flask Python:

```
@app.route('/')
def dateselect_today():
    dateselect = date.today()

    res = User.query.filter(User.date == dateselect).order_by(User.time)

    day_of_week = day_dict[dateselect.weekday()]
    date_select_full = day_of_week + ' ' + str(dateselect)

    return render_template('main_page_v2.html', result=res, date_var = date_select_full)

@app.route('/this_date/', methods=['POST'])
def dateselect_other():

    # dateselect = date.today()
    #
    # if request.method == "POST":
    dateselect = request.form['date_select']

    res = User.query.filter(User.date == dateselect).order_by(User.time)

    if dateselect == 'yesterday':
        dateselect_print = date.today()- timedelta(days=1)
    elif dateselect == 'today':
        dateselect_print = date.today()
    elif dateselect == 'tomorrow':
        dateselect_print = date.today() + timedelta(days=1)
    else:
        dateselect_print = date.today()

    day_of_week = day_dict[dateselect_print.weekday()]
    date_select_full = day_of_week + ' ' + str(dateselect_print)
    print(dateselect)
    print(dateselect)
    return render_template('main_page_v2.html', result=res, date_var = date_select_full, this_date = dateselect)
```

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='JavaScript.js') }}"></script>
<form action="{{ url_for('dateselect_other') }}" method="post">
    <button class="datebtn" name="date_select" value=yesterday>
    <script type="text/javascript">document.write(yesterday)</script>
    </button>
</form>
<form action="{{ url_for('dateselect_other') }}" method="post">
    <button class="datebtn" name="date_select" value=today>
    <script type="text/javascript">document.write(today)</script>
    </button>
</form>
<form action="{{ url_for('dateselect_other') }}" method="post">
    <button class="datebtn" name="date_select" value=tomorrow>
    <script type="text/javascript">document.write(tomorrow)</script>
    </button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
var today = new Date();
var dd1 = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
var mm1 = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
var yyyy1 = today.getFullYear();
today = yyyy1 + '-' + mm1 + '-' + dd1;

var yesterday = new Date(Date.now() - 864e5);
var dd2 = String(yesterday.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
var mm2 = String(yesterday.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
var yyyy2 = yesterday.getFullYear();
yesterday = yyyy2 + '-' + mm2 + '-' + dd2;

var tomorrow = new Date(Date.now() + 864e5);
var dd0 = String(tomorrow.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
var mm0 = String(tomorrow.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
var yyyy0 = tomorrow.getFullYear();
tomorrow = yyyy0 + '-' + mm0 + '-' + dd0;
```

Answer (score 0):

From design and performance perspective I would suggest that the method 
this_date, returns data instead of render html, using render_template actually you send back the whole html. Additionally consider that you do not submit any data request to your server so the HTTP POST is pointless, better use GET.
Besides these a quick solution might be:

PYTHON:

```
@app.route('/this_date/')
def this_date():
args = request.args
dateselect = args['dateselect']
res = User.query.filter(User.date == dateselect).order_by(User.time)
if dateselect == 'yesterday':
    dateselect_print = date.today()- timedelta(days=1)
elif dateselect == 'today':
    dateselect_print = date.today()
elif dateselect == 'tomorrow':
    dateselect_print = date.today() + timedelta(days=1)
else:
    dateselect_print = date.today()

day_of_week = day_dict[dateselect_print.weekday()]
date_select_full = day_of_week + ' ' + str(dateselect_print)
print(dateselect)
print(dateselect)
return render_template('main_page_v2.html', result=res, date_var = date_select_full, this_date = dateselect)
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='JavaScript.js') }}"></script>
<button onclick="filterByDate("today")">TODAY</button>
<button onclick="filterByDate("tomorrow")">TOMORROW</button>
<button onclick="filterByDate("yesterda")">YESTERDAY</button>
...
</html>
</body>
```

JS:

```
function filterByDate(dateFactor)
{
  const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  const host = window.location.host;
  const url= host.concat("/this_date&dateselect=").concat(dateFactor);
  console.log(url);
  Http.open("GET", url);
  Http.send();
}
```

Comment: nah, this does not seem to work. First, I dont see where the 'args = request.args' is used. Second, how is the database supposed to get querried when in this solution the 'res = User.query.filter(User.date == dateselect).order_by(User.time)' is missing?